# Detailed reference to facilitate manual implementation of ARIMAX

Tags: time-series, references, arima, arma, armax

ARIMAX is implemented in SAS and R (function [`arimax`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/TSA/docs/arimax) in "TSA" package).

I want to implement ARIMAX in an open source library in Scala and Python.

- Is there any reference, like a research paper or a step-by-step explanation, on how ARIMAX works inside (except of Rob J. Hyndman's blog post ["The ARIMAX model muddle"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/))?

Comment: R is open source so why do you not read the source code?

Comment: @Mdewey that's right, I read but I'm not familiar with R at all.

Comment: ARIMA modelling in R - https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7